# Problema ao comunicar com webservice do eSocial

Tags: c#, xml, wsdl, api

Estou com o seguinte problema ao se comunicar com webservice do eSocial, estou utilizando C# portanto adicionei a referencia do webservice no meu projeto e agora preciso enviar um XML, e o que eu pensei foi: para estabelecer uma conexão segura, antes devo definir um certificado, e abrir a conexão, e posteriormente enviar o XML. Para isso fiz da seguinte maneira:

```
// Crio a variavel de envio de lote
ServicoEnviarLoteEventosClient enviarLote = new ServicoEnviarLoteEventosClient();
```

Tenho um pequeno trecho de código que busca o certificado em questão no meu computador local e seta ele nesta variável da seguinte forma:

```
enviarLote.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
                 x509.SubjectName.Name, store.Location, StoreName.My);
```

Abro a conexão:

```
enviarLote.Open();
```

Depois tento realizar o envio:

```
var resposta = enviarLote.EnviarLoteEventos(System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Load(caminhoXML));
```

Porem ao tentar é retornado um erro: `Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority`

Tambem ja instalei a cadeia de certificados disponibilizado pelo eSocial....

Alguem poderia me ajudar ?
Caso alguém tenha duvida quanto a assinatura do XML posso ajudar...

Answer (score 3):

Obrigado pela referência à minha página de exemplos, Leo!

Eu também criei há uns tempos atrás uma página com dicas de como acessar o serviço do eSocial, incluindo algumas das que você postou na sua pergunta e resposta. Vou aproveitar o assunto da sua pergunta para colocar essas dicas aqui, para ajudar quem estiver com problemas parecidos.

Para acessar o serviço de envio do eSocial, no ambiente de Produção Restrita, a URL deve ser essa:

> https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/enviarloteeventos/WsEnviarLoteEventos.svc

Além disso, de acordo com o Manual de Orientação do Desenvolvedor do eSocial v1.6.3, página 83, item '7.9. Certificação digital', também é necessário instalar na máquina que vai acessar o serviço a **Cadeia de Certificados emitida em 06/02/2017** pelo Serpro, que são 3 certificados que podem ser obtidos nesse endereço:

> https://certificados.serpro.gov.br/serproacf/certificate-chain

Segundo o item **02.03** da página de Perguntas Frequentes do Portal do eSocial, os certificados devem ser instalados na ordem que estão dispostos nessa página do Serpro, e:
*A Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v5 deve ser instalada no repositório de AC raiz. A Autoridade Certificadora SERPRO v4 e Autoridade Certificadora do SERPRO Final v5 devem ser instaladas no repositório de AC intermediária.*

Lembrando que também é necessário ter instalado no computador que vai acessar o web service um certificado digital válido (A1 ou A3, e-CNPJ ou e-CPF), que deve ser usado para acessar o serviço. Uma dica: Quando comecei os testes com o eSocial, fiquei quase uma semana batendo a cabeça para conseguir o primeiro acesso, quando finalmente descobri que, no meu caso (e-CNPJ A1), era necessário selecionar a opção **Marcar esta chave como exportável** (*Mark this key as exportable*) e instalar meu certificado no repositório (*store*) **Pessoal** (*Personal*), do **Usuário Atual** (*Current User*).

Em relação ao código usado para acessar o serviço, o **binding** do serviço (eu usei `BasicHttpBinding` ou `BasicHttpsBinding`) deve ser configurado para usar *SecurityMode = Transport* (para o HTTPS) e *ClientCredentialType = Certificate* (para especificar um certificado), mais ou menos assim:

```
 var urlServicoEnvio = @"https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/enviarloteeventos/WsEnviarLoteEventos.svc";
 var address = new EndpointAddress(urlServicoEnvio);
 var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();  //Disponível desde .NET Framework 4.5
 // ou:
 //var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport);
 binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

 var wsClient = new WsEnviar.ServicoEnviarLoteEventosClient(binding, address);
 wsClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = x509Cert;

 var retornoEnvioXElement = wsClient.EnviarLoteEventos(loteEventosXDoc.Root);
 wsClient.Close();
```

Quanto à classe `WsEnviar.ServicoEnviarLoteEventosClient` usada no código, ela foi criada pelo Visual Studio ao adicionar uma *Service Reference*, usando a mesma URL do serviço, mas adicionando o parâmetro *?singleWsdl*:

> https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/enviarloteeventos/WsEnviarLoteEventos.svc?singleWsdl

No VS também é possível adicionar uma referência ao serviço usando diretamente o arquivo *WsEnviarLoteEventos-v1_1_0.wsdl* disponibilizado no **Pacote de Comunicação do eSocial** (última versão 1.4.1), que se encontra na página da documentação técnica do Portal do eSocial.

Essa ferramenta, *Add Service Reference* do VS, criará uma classe cliente para consumir o serviço na web, no caso do exemplo `WsEnviar.ServicoEnviarLoteEventosClient`, que herda a classe *System.ServiceModel.ClientBase*.

Também é possível usar a ferramenta de linha de comando **svcutil.exe**, que, da mesma forma, criará uma classe cliente herdando a classe *System.ServiceModel.ClientBase*. Alternativamente também é possível usar a ferramenta de linha de comando **wsdl.exe**, mais antiga, para serviços da época do .NET Framework 2, baseados em ASMX, que também criará uma classe cliente, mas dessa vez herdando a classe *System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol*. Mas nesse caso o código para consumir o serviço seria um pouco diferente.

Seguindo todos esses passos, o acesso ao web service do eSocial deve funcionar.

Comment: Segui todas as orientações e ainda assim não consegui adicionar a referencia. Poderia me dar uma ajuda? Fiz outra questão detalhando o que tentei https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/307442/como-referenciar-os-webservices-do-esocial-pelo-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver o problema de conexão segura, é necessário instalar a cadeia de certificado do governo em:

```
Autoridades de Certificação Raiz Confiáveis
```

Lembre-se, para cada certificado certifique-se de colocar nesta pasta, pois eu havia esquecido.

Para Download da Cadeia de Certificado acesse:

> https://certificados.serpro.gov.br/serproacf/certificate-chain

A estrutura de código que eu informei acima esta correta, o envio será realizado se o XML estiver estruturado de forma correta, para exemplos de XML válidos acesse:

> http://suporte.quarta.com.br/eSocial/ExemplosEventosXml.htm

Espero ter colaborado com alguém!