# Como referenciar os webservices do eSocial pelo Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, web-service, visual-studio-2015, services, api

Eu já segui as instruções [desta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/256824/problema-ao-comunicar-com-webservice-do-esocial) li, reli, e refiz várias vezes o [tutorial do Pedro Gaspar](http://suporte.quarta.com.br/eSocial/AcessandoServicos.htm). E não consigo referenciar os webservices do eSocial pelo Visual Studio. O que eu fiz até agora foi:

- Instalei as cadeias de certificados, tanto a de 15/01/2014 como a de 06/02/2017 na sequencia correta.
- Instalei as cadeias colocando todos os certificados no repositório Root da Local Machine
- Instalei as cadeias colocando somente o Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v5 no repositório Root e as demais no repositório das intermediárias.
- Instalei o Certificado (válido, não expirado e com senha correta) do meu cliente no repositório Pessoal (Na local Machine e no Usuário Atual)

Consigo acessar os endereços dos webservices pelo navegador e o cadeado fica verde.
Quando tento adicionar service reference pelo visual studio ocorre o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando fazer uma "Web Reference", acontece o seguinte:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que ele acessa o WS (pois no browser também acessa) porém, ainda aparece o forbidden.

Tentei fazer pelo SVCUTIL.EXE e o resultado foi o seguinte:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>svcutil https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/consultarloteeventos/WsConsultarLoteEventos.svc?singleWsdl
Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool
[Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Communication Foundation, Version 4.6.1055.0]
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Attempting to download metadata from 'https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/consultarloteeventos/WsConsultarLoteEventos.svc?singleWsdl' using WS-Metadata Exchange or DISCO.
Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool
[Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Communication Foundation, Version 4.6.1055.0]
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from   https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/consultarloteeventos/WsConsultarLoteEventos.svc?singleWsdl

If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have 
access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the 
specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to 
the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.

WS-Metadata Exchange Error
URI: https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/consultarloteeventos/WsConsultarLoteEventos.svc?singleWsdl

Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/consultarloteeventos/WsConsultarLoteEventos.svc?singleWsdl'.

The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.

The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

HTTP GET Error
URI: https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/consultarloteeventos/WsConsultarLoteEventos.svc?singleWsdl

There was an error downloading 'https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/consultarloteeventos/WsConsultarLoteEventos.svc?singleWsdl'.

The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden.

If you would like more help, type "svcutil /?"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Me chamou atenção as mensagens `Error: Cannot obtain Metadata...` , `Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved`  e `The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'`

Minhas possibilidades já esgotaram, não sei mais o que testar. Alguém tem uma sugestão?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ewerton, a forma mais fácil é você acessar a URL no browser:

> https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/enviarloteeventos/WsEnviarLoteEventos.svc?singleWsdl

clicar com o botão direito do mouse na página, clicar em *Save as...* e salvar um arquivo com extensão `.wsdl` na máquina local, e depois usar esse arquivo WSDL (*Web Services Description Language*) para adicionar a referência ao serviço no Visual Studio. Acho que eu fiz assim na época.

A outra forma (que aprendi agora, hehe), para você conseguir adicionar o serviço usando a URL diretamente é um pouco mais complicada, porque o Visual Studio tem que conhecer o certificado que deve ser usado para acessar um determinado endereço.

Para isso você deve acessar o Painel de Controle do Windows e fazer esse caminho (o meu Windows está em inglês, então não sei como são os nomes em português): **Control Panel** > **User Accounts** > **Credential Manager** > **Manage Windows Credentials**, na seção **Certificate-Based Credentials** você clica no link **Add a certificate-based credential**.

Você então infoma o domínio `webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br` no campo *Internet or network address*, e clica no botão **Select certificate**.

Aprendi essa dica agora com essa resposta do SO<sup>EN</sup>:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/27435343/8133067

Se estiver com o Visual Studio aberto, saia e entre novamente. Depois disso o Visual Studio deve reconhecer qual certificado usar para acessar o serviço do eSocial (no ambiente de Produção Restrita).

Comment: Sim... essa é nova pra mim, alias, é nova a possibilidade de colocar um caminho físico ali na janela de "Add Service Reference", sempre achei que só podia ser URL, coloquei o caminho do WSDL e funcionou! Obrigado

Comment: Poxa Ewerton, e o pior é que esse detalhe (de usar um caminho local), e também a resposta do Rovann Linhalis, estavam escritos lá no meu tutorial, que você leu e releu várias vezes! Mas, eu sei como é, às vezes bate o desespero e a resposta está na nossa cara e não enxergamos.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Na [Documentação Técnica](http://portal.esocial.gov.br/institucional/documentacao-tecnica) disponibilizada, tem o "[Pacote de Comunicação](http://portal.esocial.gov.br/manuais/pacote-de-comunicacao-esocial-v1-4-1.zip)".

Dentro dele, tem os WSDL para utilização do WebService. No Visual Studio, basta adicionar a "WebReference" do mesmo jeito que está fazendo, mas apontando para o arquivo na sua máquina local.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado Rovnann, nem imaginava que era possível referenciar usando o caminho de um arquivo físico, sempre achei que era obrigatório uma URL.

Answer (score 0):

A resposta do Pedro Gaspar foi fantástica!
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/307466/290686

A dica de adicionar uma credencial de windows baseada em certificado funcionou perfeitamente no código legado - VS2017 WCF FK 4.0 - que estou trabalhando no momento.

> A outra forma (que aprendi agora, hehe), para você conseguir adicionar
> o serviço usando a URL diretamente é um pouco mais complicada, porque
> o Visual Studio tem que conhecer o certificado que deve ser usado para
> acessar um determinado endereço.

Mas é fundamental fechar o VS e abri-lo novamente após a adição da credencial - ratificando o que ele também comenta na resposta original!

> Se estiver com o Visual Studio aberto, saia e entre novamente. Depois
> disso o Visual Studio deve reconhecer qual certificado usar para
> acessar o serviço do eSocial (no ambiente de Produção Restrita).

[image: Gerenciador de credenciais do windows - Adicionar credencial baseada em certificado]

[image: VS2017 Add Service Reference]

Comment: Isso não parece uma resposta. Parece mais um comentário de endosso elaborado a outra resposta. Thiago Timm o Stack Overflow não é um fórum ou rede social, nós somos um site de perguntas e respostas e esse espaço é exclusivo para responder a pergunta feita na página, não o utilize para fazer  recomendações de respostas.

Comment: @AugustoVasques: Peço perdão pela gafe, mas perceba que além de votar e "endossar" a resposta que particularmente me ajudou, ainda somei prints que acredito enriquecer a discussão... Enfim, se errei, foi por tentar somar, realmente com "boa fé".

Comment: Entendo que sua intenção é contribuir, porém o objetivo do site não é fomentar discussões. O objetivo do site é justamente evitar o debate, nós somos um Q&A e apenas isso, um usuário faz uma pergunta e outros usuários apresentam uma solução e a comunidade faz a avaliação técnica das publicações isenta de analises pessoais ou emocionais, visando apenas sermos práticos. Veja algumas orientações que vão o ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045)