# Reinf - Consumir WebService com WSDL

Tags: c#, web-service

Como consumir o WSDL do Reinf? Há algum método atualizado? Eu tentei alguns que vi aqui no StackOverflow, mas não consegui achar um funcional para poder enviar os lotes para o Reinf. Não achei nenhum que usasse os WSDL do Reinf WebServices. Alguém teria algum exemplo de como enviar os XML de lote?

Eu segui essa resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/343200/86952, mas está dando erro no objeto `ServiceReference2`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outras dúvidas que tenho:

- Como eu importo o WSDL? É só clicar nas referências e adicionar a "referência de serviço"?
- No caso para usar Produção e Pré-Produção, eu preciso trocar apenas a URL e esse ServiceReference? E no caso do ServiceReference, eu passo a URL do Reinf?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei se é o certo, mas eu baixei os WSDL direto do Site do Reinf (zip), e adicionei a URL dele no "Adicionar Referência de Serviço", então eu importei. Ele ficou em "Connected Services", coloquei então o nome dele no lugar do "ServiceReference2". Parece que funcionou.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você já viu essa resposta aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/343200/86952 ?

Comment: acabei de ver, pode me informar se ainda funciona em 2021? talvez tenha atualizado a forma de usar. e no meu caso, se eu tento usar esse codigo do link, ele dá um erro em uma parte, vou anexar na pergunta. não sei o que precisa fazer aqui. Ele pede para gerar uma Classe, é isso mesmo?

Comment: Esse `ServiceReference2`, que está dando erro, seria o WSDL que você importou para o projeto. Que nome você deu para essa referência de serviço?

Comment: é nisso que fiquei em duvida mesmo, esse WSDL, como eu importo ele? é só clicar nas referencias e adicionar a "Referencia se serviço?". uma duvida, no caso pra eu usar de Produção e Pre-Produção, eu preciso trocar apenas a Url e esse ServiceReference? e no caso do ServiceReference, eu passo a URL do Reinf? como: "https://preprodefdreinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/wsreinf/RecepcaoLoteReinf.svc"?

Comment: Nao sei se é o certo, mas eu baixei os WSDL direto do Site do Reinf(Zip), e adicionei a URL dele no "Adicionar Referencia de Serviço", ai eu importei. ele ficou em "Connected Services", ai coloquei o nome dele no lugar do "ServiceReference2". parece que funcionou.

Comment: Para importar o WSDL, veja essa outra resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/307466/86952, é sobre o eSocial, mas a ideia é a mesma no caso do EFD-Reinf. Se puder, dê um voto positivo nas respostas (e perguntas) que forem úteis a você! (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Comment: na verdade, eu ja tenho os WSDL, são aqueles da 1 foto, eu baixei o pacote do site do Reinf, tem o de envio e consulta. eu digo no sentido, pra importar ele, é só adicionar na Referencia de serviço e usar mesmo não é?(coloquei uma foto de como ficaram) e uma duvida, pra eu poder trocar entre Produção e a Restrita, eu só preciso trocar a URL e o WsClient?

Comment: Eu agrupei todas as informações em uma resposta para sua pergunta. Se ela resolver seu problema, por favor marque-a como resposta e dê um voto positivo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para adicionar uma referência aos web services do EFD-Reinf, primeiro baixe os arquivos WSDL do projeto:

> [WSDL Serviços EFD-REINF - Producao.zip](http://sped.rfb.gov.br/arquivo/show/2548)
> [WSDL Serviços EFD-REINF - Producao Restrita.zip](http://sped.rfb.gov.br/arquivo/download/2916)

No Visual Studio acesse o menu *Project* > *Add Service Reference* e aponte o endereço do arquivo WSDL local que acabou de baixar, dando um nome para o serviço, por exemplo `ReinfEnvio`. Para outras opções veja essa outra resposta: [Como referenciar os webservices do eSocial pelo Visual Studio?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/307466/86952).

Não é necessário adicionar referência para os dois ambientes, **Produção** e **Produção Restrita**. Se você comparar o conteúdo dos arquivos WSDL verá que a única coisa que muda entre um e outro é somente o `soap:address`:

**Webservice de Envio de Lote de Eventos**

> Produção: https://reinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/WsReinf/RecepcaoLoteReinf.svc
> Produção Restrita: https://preprodefdreinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/WsReinf/RecepcaoLoteReinf.svc

**Webservice de Consulta**

> Produção: https://reinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/WsReinfConsultas/ConsultasReinf.svc
> Produção Restrita: https://preprodefdreinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/WsReinfConsultas/ConsultasReinf.svc

Então só seria necessário adicionar duas referências de serviço, a do serviço de envio (`ReinfEnvio`) e a do serviço de consulta (`ReinfConsulta`).

O código para acessar o WebService do EFD-Reinf é basicamente esse abaixo. Eu copiei da resposta: [Como consumir WebService do EFD-Reinf no C#? (Envio Eventos)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/343200/86952), alterando apenas o nome do serviço e a possibilidade de chavear entrar os endereços de Produção e Produção Restrita:

```cs
using System.Net;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public void EnviarLoteReinf()
{
   // Carrega o certificado digital a partir de um arquivo PFX, informando a senha.
   X509Certificate2 x509Cert = new X509Certificate2(caminhoArquivoPfx, senhaArquivoPfx);
   // Carrega o XML de lote a partir de um arquivo.
   // Mas os XMLs dos eventos devem ser assinados digitalmente antes de inseridos no XML de lote.
   // Para isso é possível usar a função SignXmlDoc() disponível na resposta abaixo:
   // https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277476/
   XDocument loteEventosXDoc = XDocument.Load(caminhoArquivoXml);

   var urlServicoEnvio = @"https://{0}.receita.fazenda.gov.br/WsReinf/RecepcaoLoteReinf.svc";
   if (producao)
      urlServicoEnvio = String.Format(urlServicoEnvio, "reinf");
   else
      urlServicoEnvio = String.Format(urlServicoEnvio, "preprodefdreinf");

   var address = new EndpointAddress(urlServicoEnvio);
   // BasicHttpsBinding está disponível somente a partir do .NET Framework 4.5.
   // Se estiver usando uma versão anterior, use a linha comentada abaixo.
   //var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport);
   var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();

   // Informa que será usado um certificado digital para acessar o serviço.
   binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

   // Veja essa pergunta para mais detalhes:
   // https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/318351/
   ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

   // Cria o objeto cliente (do tipo System.ServiceModel.ClientBase) para acesso ao WebService.
   var wsClient = new ReinfEnvio.RecepcaoLoteReinfClient(binding, address);
   // Passa o certificado digital para o objeto do tipo System.ServiceModel.ClientBase.
   wsClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = x509Cert;

   // Veja: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49303859/
   wsClient.Open();
   // Chama o WebService de fato, passando o XML do lote.
   // O método espera um objeto do tipo XElement, e retorna outro objeto XElement.
   var retornoEnvioXElement = wsClient.ReceberLoteEventos(loteEventosXDoc.Root);
   wsClient.Close();
}
```

Esse código é apenas para o serviço de envio (que no caso do exemplo eu chamei de `ReinfEnvio`), mas para o serviço de consulta seria a mesma coisa, usando os endereços da consulta, e o objeto do serviço de consulta (`ReinfConsulta`).

Note que esse código não está completo, já que precisaria receber as informações do certificado digital, bem como do arquivo XML de lote para o envio. Ele apenas mostra a base de como seria acessar o Web Service do EFD-Reinf para o envio de um lote de eventos.

Comment: Agradeço Pedro, eu tinha conseguido antes e fiquei em duvida quando á  troca entre Produção e Pré-Produção, mas isso já sanou minha duvida. agradeço pela ajuda.